# UITableViewCell dynamic height with image

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uitableview

How cant i achieve this effect with UITableViewController and UITableViewCell.

[image]
i just tried to set the `image.hidden = true` when there is an image and `image.hidden = false` when is not, but the blank space does not dissapear.
Some ideas to achieve this?? Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want image height to effectively become 0 when you set the image to hidden? Are you using auto-layout?

Comment: Maybe in your `heightForRowAtIndexPath()` method, set the height of the cell to be smaller if you dont want to display the image, and larger if you do. Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath()` either show the image or don't.

Comment: @myles yes, im using auto-layout, and i did what you said, and it works, but i got constraints errors like this: 

`Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
`

Answer (score 1):

In this case I suggest you should update your constraints dynamically.Connect height constraint of your imageview to your viewcontroller.

```
 @IBOutlet var MyHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

and set its value as 0 when the imageview is hidden

```
MyHeightConstraint.constant = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You should handle this in your UITableViewController. Assuming you are using autolayout, you should setup your constraints in order to work with and without the image.
For example let's assume that your cell it's just an UIImageView and a UILabel.

```
-----------
UIImageView
UILabel
-----------
```

You should pin your imageView top,right,left.
You should pin your label bottom,right,left and have 2 constraints top. One to the imageView, and one to superView. The first one with 999 priority and the second one with 500.

In your VC, when determining the cell height, if there is no images, you will have to:

1. Invert priorities
2. ImageView.alpha = 0
3. [self layoutIfNeeded]

Also, if your constraints are setup properly, you can even do something like this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 YourCellClass *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kIdentifier];
// here you make your validations and setup your cell as we said before
// something like [cell setupForImage:UIImage andText:text];
return [cell systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
}
```

With this you should not even care to hardcode your height, the cell will do it for you.

Hope it helps!!